# Modulus of continuity of pointwise exponentiation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lipschitz-functions

For a $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, I am considering the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as

$$ f_{\alpha}(x) = |x|^{\alpha} \operatorname{sign}(x) $$

where the absolute value, the sign, and the multiplication are *pointwise*.

For $p\in \mathbb{N}$ it is fairly easy to show that

$$ || f_p(x_1) - f_p(x_2)||_2 \leq p \; ||x_1 - x_2||_2 \; \max(||x_1||_2, ||x_2||_2)^{p-1}.$$

**Question**: Does the above inequality also hold for $\alpha = 1/p$ with $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and for a general constant $C>0$ on the rhs (instead of $p$)?

**Remark 1**: Numerical experiments suggest that this is true. However, my proof for the case $p \in \mathbb{N}$ only works for $\alpha \ge 1$ and I can show the general result only for $n=1$.

**Remark 2**: I would be perfectly happy to replace $\max(||x_1||_2, ||x_2||_2)^{\alpha-1}$ by $\max(1,||x_1||_2, ||x_2||_2)^{\alpha-1}$ if that helps.

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|} \cdot \operatorname{sign}(x)$ is not Lipschitz continuous in any neighbourhood of $x=0$.

Comment: @MartinR: That is true. However, the inequality above still holds close to zero if 1 is used as a constant on the rhs instead of 1/p (I updated the question accordingly). Probably the 'locally Lipschitz' in the title is misleading.